# Can I call TLS callbacks manually?

Tags: c++, windows, compression, thread-local-storage

I'm trying to make an executable packer in C++ and I've managed to make a PE loader for 64bit, resolve executable imports, make all the relocations, added some anti-debugging tricks, but if I compress any executable with TLS callbacks it won't run. If the executable doesn't have any TLS callbacks, everything is working fine.

Can someone give me some tips about how TLS should be handled in packers ? Do I have to parse TLS callbacks and call them with a `PIMAGE_TLS_CALLBACK` before I make the call to the entry point ?